# placing text beside an image using inline-block problems

Tags: html, css

I want to use the inline-block feature to keep everything responsive but I am running into a problem.

**The problem is that my background image isn't showing up and they aren't horizontal (side by side) as opposed to how they are now stacked on top of each other .. what am I missing?**

I've quickly recreated the problem I am having here:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/1/)**

HTML:

```
<section>
                    <div class="first">
                        <p>hello this is some text</p><p>and here is some more text </p>
                    <div class="ipad"></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    display: inline-block;
}

.ipad {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/IPad_3.png/220px-IPad_3.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

I'm probably missing something quite simple, I have Google much and still am at a loss.

Comment: You didn't tell what is the problem

Comment: @Cherniv sorry about that, I added some clarification.

Comment: Are you want to see paragraphs side by side and the image behide of them ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things ..

1. If you want your paragraphs `<p>` to come inline, you need to add `inline-block` to them, and not their parent :

   ```
   .first p{
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```
2. Your image will show if you provide its height and width in the div's style.

   ```
   .ipad {
       background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/IPad_3.png/220px-IPad_3.png) no-repeat;
       display: inline-block;
       border: 1px solid #333;
       height:100px; //<- provide height
       width:100px; //<- provide width
   }
   ```

**EDIT :** To have all your children come inline no matter how wide they are, use this on their parent `.first` :

```
.first{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Updated fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/2/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I get a significant portion of text to be beside the image now? because it looks like it's only at the bottom.

Comment: To have the image come inline no matter how wide it is, use this : `.first{ white-space:nowrap; }`

Comment: I've added my styles to the section and now I run into the same problem, it seems to be happening from the font-size.. any idea?? http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/6/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
p {
   float: left
}
```

for side by side paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order for the ipad image to appear, you need to give the div a dimension:

```
.ipad {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/IPad_3.png/220px-IPad_3.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 220px;
    height: 274px;
}
```

Then set `float:left` or `display:inline-block` on the `<p>` to make them move next to each other:

```
.first p{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/3/

If you want the background image behind the paragraphs then do something like this:

```
.first{
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/IPad_3.png/220px-IPad_3.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 220px;
    height: 274px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.first p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/4/